# Can I fix (Error 1014 CNAME Cross-User Banned) or not as an API user?

Tags: http, error-handling, cors

I'm using commercejs for an e-commerce project, and I'm pushing to the platform some images I store into S3. Today I opened the application and I see that images can't be rendered. In the platform I have the same situation, they're not rendered. I thought the problem is that S3 updated it's urls, which is not the case as I checked them. Then I manually grabbed an image url from the platform and it gives me the error from title, which is somehow related to Cloudflair, and I guess the problem can be solved only from the api owners, am I right? I can't do anything to solve this error? Thank you!

Comment: I guess the problem is from the platform, because when I upload manually an image to the platform, it is also not rendered, so the problem obviously is from the platform.